# How does one physically and intuitively interpret the combination of SI units?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, si-units, intuition

What i mean by the question is this:
If derive a formula using some simple observations and I receive a unit for that formula that I cannot intuitively understand it as I can for e.g. the speed of an object or its acceleration or even the force applied to and object, but I get such a unit which is a combination of SI units that don't make sense when I think about what it could mean using a sentence like " $1\ \frac{m}{s}$ is the speed of an object which traversed a distance of $1\ m$ in $1\ s$ ".

I want to know if there is a full proof way to make a sentence which will put any unit into perspective.

Comment: Similar to what is presented in the answers, but going the "opposite direction" is the case of [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse), the impulse delivered by a rocket engine per unit of propellent weight. A table of specific impulse will report the values is units of seconds.  It takes some head-scratching to figure out what that time interval represents but it can be done.  But the definition of impulse per Newton (weight) is fairly easy to grasp.

Answer (score 4):

Putting things into perspective isn't really about physics, but one's understanding. That force is $[N]=[kg][m][s]^{-2}$ is pretty opaque to me, despite having known $F=ma$ since I was a kid. Newton's formula is much clearer than the units since it explains what is going on.

Hence there is no proof or standard method that will make a bunch of units turn into something physically meaningful. Part of this is that it is not unique: power is expressed as $[W]=[kg][m]^2[s]^{−3}$, but you could of course think of it as $[N][m][s]^{-1}$ and say it is a force times a velocity. In some situations that might actually be a good description of something in a system. Fuel efficiency is measured in fuel volume per distance travelled, or $[m]^{2}$, but seeing it as an area is usually a weird perspective*.

So in general, when you get something like $[m]^{-2}[kg]^{-1}[s]^3[K]$ it is better to look at what things in the problem description give rise to it and how to interpret the unit than try to reverse-engineer a physical meaning just from the units. Sometimes it can be done, but often there are multiple confusing choices. Real experts will of course immediately recognize the units (aha! thermal resistance!) but that happens once one is very used to the physics and units, not through any formal method.

[ *: If your car has a fuel efficiency of area $A$, that corresponds to the cross-section of an imaginary string of fuel along the road that is thick enough to propel the car forward at the relevant velocity. ]

Answer (score 2):

There's probably not a foolproof method for a complicated unit by iteself, since e.g. torque and energy have the same dimension. However, for most quantities, you can understand the units by looking at the definition of the quantity itself and its relation to simpler ones.

Some examples:

- You choose a set of "base" units, such as metre, second, kilogram, Ampere and Kelvin. Here, you implicitly think of "base quantities" (length, time (duration), mass, current, temperature) that should be intuitive to you.
- From these base quantities, you can derive others. For example, velocity should be intuitively clear and is measured in length/time, i.e. m/s. Acceleration may already be less intuitive, but it clearly is change of velocity per time, so $\left(\text{m}/\text{s}\right)/\text{s}=\text{m}/\text{s}^2$.
- Force is essentially defined by $F=ma$, so its unit is $\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}/\text{s}^2$, which is also called Newton. In other words, a force accelerates a massive object, and one Newton gives an object of one kg an acceleartion of one metre per square second.
- Mechanical energy (or work) can be defined by pushing something with some force, so $\text{d}W=F \text{d}s$ -- one Joule $\text{J}=\text{N}\, \text{m}=\text{kg}\:\text{m}^2/\text{s}^2$ is the work done by pushing something with one Newton over a distance of one metre.
- Torque, on the other hand, is $\vec \tau=\vec F\times \vec r$, so it is measured in $\text{N} \, \text{m}$, as is energy. The interpretation is different though: A torque of $ 1 \text{N}\,\text{m}$ corresponds to a force of one Newton acting via a crank of one metre in length.

In a similar way, you can try to construct the "intuitive meaning" of some unit by looking at the quantity. (For example, the thermal resistance tells you how large a temperature difference needs to be to sustain a given heat flow.)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes: the SI units are self-consistent.
It can get quite complicated quite quickly, however.

For example, if I have the irradiance (the flux of electromagnetic radiation), has units of
$W / m^2$, which can be seen as one unit of power that crosses an area of one square meter, or as $J / s / m^2$, that is, as one unit of energy that crosses an area of one square meter each second and so on.